# How to measure page download time with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I go about measuring page download+rendering time of a website in selenium (Python)? Currently I have something like

```
... # set up web driver and loop through a list of domain names

print currDomainName
start = datetime.now()
browser.get(currDomainName)
end = datetime.now()

... # do something with the time diff
```

But it doesn't quite work because `get()` isn't guaranteed to block until page render is complete. Its [official doc](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) also says

> In some circumstances, WebDriver may return control before the page has finished, or even started, loading.

In fact, in my short test code the print statement could literally be printing two or three urls further down before the one in webdriver finishes loading.

I know using explicit wait on certain webpage elements can enforce blocking, but is there a generic way of doing this? I'm measuring this on about a few thousand websites, so it would be great to have something independent from the web content.

Answer (score 1):

Only way how to make sure that everything is loaded is to use [ExplicitWait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp). Downside is that you have to know which element slows the rendering of each particular page but this is the only way how to keep your measure precise.

```
start = datetime.now()
browser.get(currDomainName)
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 
   "reallyHugeImageId")))
end = datetime.now()
```

Note that `time.sleep()` would break your measures because you would always wait exact time. So only way is to investigate which elements are not yet rendered even if the `WebDriver` returns and wait from them through `ExpectedCondition`.

Comment: so basically, there's no reliable way of measuring this?

Comment: I am afraid not - I am also not convinced that Selenium is right tool for such testing, Selenium is generally slower then users browser and this kind of performance can be affected by many parameters (server load, number of users online, speed of your machine, etc... which you can't simulate by Selenium) so I definitely wouldn't rely on it here...

Comment: Hm yeah thought so.. Do you by chance know any better tool for this type of measurements(just page load time, nothing more)? Selenium was the only one I found that has decent amount of users and looked promising

Comment: @PetrMensik What do you mean Selenium is slower than a browser? Selenium uses an actual browser. Selenium might add some insignificant overhead, but what other tool would be better than one that uses the same tool a real user would use?