# Python function to log refresh times of a web page

Tags: python, function, logging, time, refresh

I am trying to write a program that will refresh a webpage and log the time it takes to refresh the webpage. So far I have this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.GoogleChrome()
driver.get("https://www.wikipedia.org/")
driver.refresh()
```

I was wondering how I would go about timing the page refreshing. I am not sure where to find the loading time or how to calculate it

Comment: Hi Wil, There are many ways to measure "elapsed time" in Python. Do a simple search and choose the easiest or more adapt for your case. if you are looking for some specific function in Selenium, make it clear, because that does not came out from the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to measure page download time with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026493/how-to-measure-page-download-time-with-selenium)